# Good tournament that each vertex has outdegree d

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

consider the tournament good if the outdegree of all vertices is d and number of common outdegree neighbors of each 2 vertices is L, consider a good tournament G that has n vertices

a)prove that each edge of G is in exactly (n-3)/4 directed triangle

b)the number of directed triangles in terms of n.

c)assume n=11. T(G) is the minimum number of edges that need to be removed such that the remaining graph doesn't contain a directed cycle. prove T(G) > c(n,2)/3

My attempt:
for part a get 2 vertices and consider the edges between their indegree and outdegree neighbours(and each 2 vertices have the same indegree too) and for part b I wanted to use double-counting using the proof of the first part and I'm stuck in part c

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, This is a hard problem, i didnt have a good idea and considering it was an exam I didn't give this one much thought

Comment: What is $n$? you just start referencing it without ever defining what it is.

Comment: number of vertices of the graph

Comment: i solved it, thanks.